# SSRS - Save multi-value parameter to a temp Table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, multivalue

I have a multi-value parameter @ID in a report, with 100 values, and I need to collect the values selected in a temp table to further process them, then display the parameters into the report. How can I save the parameters selected into a temp table, one value in each row?

```
 ID: 
    1
    2
    3
    ...
    100
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by "Further process them"? Sometimes telling us your final goal helps

Comment: If your dataset query is not a stored proc AND they values originally came from a table then you can do this. More info needed but if they came from say a products table then you could just do `SELECT ProductID INTO #temp FROM myProducts WHERE ProductID in (@ID)`

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield ! I have not thought about this simple solution. I have used a table to pull the rows together and this works.

Comment: I'll add the comment as an answer so the question can be marked as answered, otherwise it will appear as though it still requires work.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset query is not a stored proc AND they values originally came from a table then you can do this.

Assuming the IDs came from say, a products table,  then you could just do

```
SELECT ProductID INTO #temp FROM myProducts WHERE ProductID in (@ID)
```

This method is generally basis for most of my dataset queries although I would not use a temp table I would simply query my data and apply the parameter in the `WHERE` clause as above.